# Loop with after() in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a newbie with Tkinter and am still very unsure of the things I am trying to do, hopefully it is not to stupid. Every help is welcome.

I want to use my Rasberry Pi to controll some motors. These motors put ingredients together. It works fine in Python, but I want to have a GUI with a few buttons. Each button should put a recipe in a function makerecipe. A recipe consists of a list of times how long the different motors should be activated. Makerecipe will activate the the GPIO pins.

Then a new function motor should start. Here it checks when the motors should be deactivated. It is a simpel trick which works in Python, but I don't know how to make it work in Tkinter. Every second a loop checks whether the time passed is equal to what is in the recipe. If this is so, the motor is deactivated.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
uitput = StringVar() #I want to print what is happening to label L2
uitput.set('Nothing')  #when program starts it says 
conversie = [7, 11, 15] #I will use pins 7, 11 and 15 on the RPi, 
moj = [0, 0, 2] #recipe 1, through Button 1, number of seconds the pins are True
sob = [4, 0, 0] #recipe 2, through Button 2, number of seconds the pins are True

#The following function activates the pins which are used in making the recipe
#later this will just activate the pins, for now it shows it in a label on screen.
#this seems to work

def makerecipe(argu): 
    aa=[]
    for i in range(len(argu)):
        if argu[i]==0:
            a=('GPIO.output(', str(conversie[i]), 'False)')
            aa.append(a)
        else:
            b=('GPIO.output(', str(conversie[i]), 'True)')
            aa.append(b)
    uitput.set(aa)
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.motor(argu)

#Next I want to have a function that looks at recipe and reads how long the
#GPIO pins should be active. Then turns them off one at a time. I just don't
#understand the after function. 
#I think, but probably wrong, that my recipe was loaded in makerecipe and argu
#has the value of the recipe because of the button, and I hoped I could pass argu
#along to the function motor.


def motor(motorinput):
    resultaat=('bla')
    uitput.set(resultaat)
`enter code here`    cc=[]
    for MotorNum in range(max(motorinput)+1):
        if MotorNum in motorinput:
            if motorinput.index(MotorNum)==0:
                c=("GPIO.output(",conversie[motorinput.index(MotorNum)],", False)")
                cc.append(c)
            elif motorinput.index(MotorNum)==1:
                d=("GPIO.output(",conversie[motorinput.index(MotorNum)],", False)")
                cc.append(d)
            elif motorinput.index(MotorNum)==2:
                e=("GPIO.output(",conversie[motorinput.index(MotorNum)],", False)")
                cc.append(e)
        uitput.set(cc)
        root.update_idletasks()
        #root.after(1000, motor(alfa)) #This goes wrong. 

B= Button(root, text="optie 1", command=lambda: makerecipe(moj))
B.pack()
L2=Label(root, textvariable=uitput, width=100)
L2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The reason I am printing my entire code here is that it might help to know what the hell I am trying, it probably looks dreadful but I am trying to get better at it.

First question is I apparently don't understand how to call the next function motor inside my first function. It stops there and gives me: AttributeError: motor

Second question is I know how to work with time.sleep, but I read everywhere on this forum that you should not do this. So I am trying to use after, but don't know how to use this properly.

I hope somebody can help this total novice. I understand the logic of Python quite well, but Tkinter is a new way of thinking for me.

Answer (score 1):

> First question is I apparently don't understand how to call the next function motor inside my first function. It stops there and gives me: AttributeError: motor

The problem is in last line of *makerecipe* function:

```
root.motor(argu)
```

The variable *root* is a TK object which does not have a motor function. That's the reason for AttributeError. Changing this line to:

```
motor(argu)
```

Would remove this error.

> Second question is I know how to work with time.sleep, but I read everywhere on this forum that you should not do this. So I am trying to use after, but don't know how to use this properly.

You should use after because Tk has an eventloop running (the *root.mainloop()* call) to react based on events (like calling your functions when a button is clicked, or a certain time has passed). But if you use *time.sleep* in your code, you might interfere with this eventloop.

The fix is that you should pass a function reference to *after*, so Tk eventloop would call that function when the right time comes. But here, you are calling the function right away:

```
root.after(1000, motor(alfa)) #This goes wrong.
```

This line is calling *motor* (and passing *alfa* as argument) and then passing the return value of motor (which could be anything) to *root.after*.

This line should be like this:

```
root.after(1000, motor, alfa)
```

Now we are telling *root* to call *motor* with the *alfa* argument, after 1 second.